# ASP.NET core shared view cannot access .js and .css libs

Tags: css, asp.net, view, src, shared

I am working on ASP.NET core 3.1. I want to do a simple application. I have a very basic problem but I cannot find a good way to solve it.

I have the menu of the application in a Shared view _Layout.cshtml. In this view i am loading .js and .css libs with:

```
<script src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Everything is working fine, the menu is correctly displayed, and I can display my Index.cshtml with the @RenderBody().

The problem is that when I want to go to another page using:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy" aria-expanded="false"><span>Privacy</span></a>
```

or

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Privacy", "Home")"><span>Privacy</span></a>
```

the page will be loaded trying to fetch the libs from :

```
<script src="Home/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And it won't find them.

I would like to know what is the best practice to avoid this issue.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In asp .net core static files should be placed inside **wwwroot**  folder. Thats why put static files inside wwwroot folder and give reference to _Layout.cshtml like this,

```
<script src="~/JavaScript/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/CSS/styles.css"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shusil. I was using the wwwroot but I didn't know about the ~/.
it works well now ;-)